# Split dataframe into certain number of groups in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe with 285000 records and I want to split it in 10 dataframes that I could save and access easily. I am trying to split it like this but I am not sure how to save all dataframes separately:

```
groups <- c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8", "x9", "x10")
X <- split(data5, f = groups)
```

Like this I only receive one subset dataframe.

Comment: Instead of f = groups, have you tried data5$groupingVar, where groupingVar is the column that contains values x1, x2, etc?

Comment: i want to split by rows and not columns..

Comment: Are you expecting the output to be 10 dataframes of equal length and named x1..x10?

Comment: yes, this is the expected output

Comment: That's not what split does. The second argument is a grouping variable (anything coercible to factor) that determines how to split the data. You could make a new variable with a repeating sequence of 1:10, then use that vector as the second argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `split` your `data` and save it seperately, I would recommend the following approach using `tidyverse`.

**Split the data**

```
# libraries;
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

# split data according to some
# variable and store

data_list <- mtcars %>% split(
        f = .$cyl
) %>% set_names(
        nm = paste("cylinder", names(.), sep = "")
)
```

Here, `f = .$cyl` refers to your grouping variable in the dataset of interest. In this example Ive split the data according to `cyl` in `mtcars`.

The function splits according to each level inside the `data`. In this case 4, 6 and 8 cylinders.

I proceed with `set_names` from `purrr` to name each element of the list accordingly.

**Saving the data**

```
# store and save locally
# by using map

map(
        .x = 1:length(data_list),
        .f = function(i) {
                
                # set name of data to save locally
                path <- paste(names(data_list[i]), ".csv", sep = "")
                
                # save with fwrite
                fwrite(
                        data_list[[i]],
                        file = path,
                        sep  = ";"
                )
                
                
        }
)
```

I use `map` to iterate through the entire length of the list which `split` creates, and save them locally according to the names we set above with `fwrite` from `data.table` for better performance.

Note that in the script each data is saves as `paste(names(data_list[i]), ".csv", sep = "")`, which evaluates to `cylinder4.csv`, `cylinder6.csv` and `cylinder8.csv`.

The same approach to your data should be readily applicable with minor changes in the script.

Best

Answer (score 0):

If you want to arbitrarily split a big dataframe into little ones, you can add to the dataframe a uniformly distributed grouping variable, then use split.

```
df <- data.frame(group = rep(1:3, 4),
                 val = runif(12))

df

   group       val
1      1 0.5883321
2      2 0.5704967
3      3 0.7866597
4      1 0.8685778
5      2 0.6580090
6      3 0.1036386
7      1 0.7858867
8      2 0.2679281
9      3 0.2577965
10     1 0.6040585
11     2 0.6987716
12     3 0.2328914
> 

split(df, x$groupVal)

> $a
   group       val
2      2 0.5704967
5      2 0.6580090
8      2 0.2679281
11     2 0.6987716

$b
   group       val
1      1 0.5883321
4      1 0.8685778
7      1 0.7858867
10     1 0.6040585

$c
   group       val
3      3 0.7866597
6      3 0.1036386
9      3 0.2577965
12     3 0.2328914
```